# Rebase or Merge in Git - Local Copy Behind

Tags: git, bitbucket, commit, rebase

I have a bit of a situation.
Right now, I have a `master` branch, and a `feature` branch that is 9 commits ahead of the `master`.
I also have a local copy of the `master` that has been updated.

I am trying to come up with the best way to get both of the `feature` branches merged into the `master`.
Is this a case for a rebase?

Right now I am thinking to merge the `feature` branch that is 9 commits ahead into the `master` and then try to push the local copy ontop of that?

I don't think that will work the way I want though.
Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what "a local copy of the master that has been updated." means.

If it means master was fetch and has new commits from the remote, then yes, a rebase of the feature branch on top of master is a good idea.
(Assuming you are alone working on that feature branch)

```
   (master)
      |
m--m--m--m--m (origin/master)
       \
        f--f--f--f--f--f--f--f--f (feature)

git switch feature
git rebase origin/master

     (origin/master)
            |
m--m--m--m--m--f'--f'--f'--f'--f'--f'--f'--f'--f' (feature)

git push --force
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.

The local copy was updated with features but has not been commited yet.

I am thinking I should commit the local copy back to the master.  Then rebase the feature branch onto the master.  Does that sound correct?  

Thank you

Comment: @Cleveland_Alex Not sure what the local copy is... master? It is best to leave master untouched. No new commits. Then rebase feature on top of it in order to make sure that feature works on top of master commits.

Comment: Yes the locally copy is mastr, that then had work done on it.  We were unaware that another dev branch had exisited with 9 commits.

Comment: Then yes, rebate on top of local master, and force push feature.